# Android multitouch event indexes

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am experiencing a problem where multitouch events are causing touch indexes to be released when the finger is still pressed.

My Java wrapper code is pasted below. The function passes the activePointer integer to a C++ function which stores the up/down state in an array, using the activePointer value as the array index. Down events set the array value to true and up events set the array value to false.

Behavior is as follows:

- If one finger is pressed, touch index 0 is true.
- If two fingers are pressed touch index 0 and 1 are both true.
- If the second finger is then removed, touch index 0 is true and touch index 1 is false (as expected).
- If instead the first finger is removed and the second finger is left touching, both touch index 0 and 1 are false. I would expect touch index 0 to be false, and touch index 1 to still be true.

This is my Java wrapper code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Integer activePointer = (event.getAction() >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
    Float x = event.getX(activePointer);
    Float y = event.getY(activePointer);

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        // Log.i("touchtest", "action_down " + activePointer.toString() +
        // "(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        androidRenderer.touch(x, y, activePointer);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // Log.i("touchtest", "action_move " + activePointer.toString() +
        // "(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        androidRenderer.move(x, y, activePointer);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        // Log.i("touchtest", "action_up " + activePointer.toString() + "("
        // + x + "," + y + ")");
        androidRenderer.up(x, y, activePointer);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html), but it is not very clear.

I messed around with the `event.findPointerIndex` function, but couldn't deduce any pattern in what it was actually doing.

I can't imagine this is a rare problem.  Can someone with experience with this offer your advice?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not work much with multitouch events but maybe including a default case in your switch statement could help.

Answer (score 0):

`(event.getAction() >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT)` will give you only pointer index. Pointer index may change during whole multitouch gesture.

What you actually need is a pointer ID. `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT` name is a bit confusing since it returns Pointer Index instead of Pointer ID thus it was deprecated and renamed to MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT since API 8. Pointer ID uniquely identifies a pointer.

To get pointer ID use [getPointerId(activePointer)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId(int)).

Pass pointer ID to `androidRenderer.xxx(x, y, activePointerId);` and you should be fine.